# Can't compile Cuda samples on macbook pro 2010

Tags: c++, macos, cuda

I'm trying to compile cuda-samples on my macbook pro 2010 Nvidia 320M running OSx 10.11 and got those errors.

```
AhmadsMacbookPro:NVIDIA_CUDA-5.5_Samples iartist93$ make
/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.5/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++ -I../../common/inc  -m64 -Xcompiler -arch -Xcompiler x86_64   -gencode arch=compute_10,code=sm_10 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=\"sm_35,compute_35\" -o asyncAPI.o -c asyncAPI.cu
2016-03-12 21:16:13.470 xcodebuild[1278:29992] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 9AFF134A-08DC-4096-8CEE-62A4BB123046 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Unity4XC.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2016-03-12 21:16:13.473 xcodebuild[1278:29992] Failed to load plugin at: /Users/iartist93/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Unity4XC.xcplugin, skipping.  Reason for failure: *** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
2016-03-12 21:16:15.958 xcodebuild[1281:30115] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 9AFF134A-08DC-4096-8CEE-62A4BB123046 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Unity4XC.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2016-03-12 21:16:15.959 xcodebuild[1281:30115] Failed to load plugin at: /Users/iartist93/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Unity4XC.xcplugin, skipping.  Reason for failure: *** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
clang: error: unsupported option '-dumpspecs'
clang: error: no input files
make[1]: *** [asyncAPI.o] Error 1
make: *** [0_Simple/asyncAPI/Makefile.ph_build] Error 2
```

I'm installing Cuda 5.5 driver and toolkit as the newest version (7.5) doesn't supported on this macbook pro model and i heard that some people succeed to run Cuda 5.5 on this model.

Anyone can help solving this issue please?

Thanks

Comment: CUDA 5.5 doesn't support clang as a host compiler. I doubt you will be able to get CUDA 5.5 to work on 10.11

Comment: So should i downgrade to 10.10 or upgrade Cuda ?

Comment: No 10,10 either. CUDA 5.5 is available as  10.7, & 10.8 or 10.9 packages.

Comment: Can my macbook pro model support a newer version of Cuda?

Comment: You will probably have to do both.  I think either CUDA 6 or 6.5 will be the last one with compute 1.x device support, you  will need to read the release notes and getting started guides to work out which combination of CUDA and OS will work on your hardware.

Comment: This is really a duplicate of this recent question http://stackoverflow.com/q/35879563/681865